# Laravel appended attribute blocking AJAX query

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-api

I have a model called OrdenesTrabajo. I have an appended field called 'show_personal' like so:

```
    protected $appends = [
      'show_personal', 
    ];
```

```
    public function getShowPersonalAttribute() {
      $data = [];      
      $arrPersonal =  json_decode($this->personal);
      if($arrPersonal) {
        foreach ($arrPersonal as $key => $value) {
            $data[] = Personal::find($value);
        }      
      }
      return $data;
    }
```

The appended field causes no problem when used in a Controller which redirects to a view. But the problem comes when I have to consult the OrdenesTrabajo model using AJAX calling a controller action, to make it work in the API controller method I have to add `->makeHidden('show_personal')` because it won't load, it just keeps loading until it reaches a timeout with message: `No data found for resource with given identifier`. Making the appended field hidden makes the ajax query work, so I assume it's something in the appended field that's causing the problem here. It's not an option to make it hidden because I need the data.

I've also tried making the appended field hidden in the model, and making it visible when I need it but it keeps doing the same thing (loading the ajax query until timeout).

Extra info: I'm using Laravel 5.8
Thanks in advance, my apologies for any grammar mistakes.

Comment: I ran into something like this recently, where I had an `$appends = ['whatever']`, and `public function getWhateverAttribute()` executed a query to load a Model that _also_ had an `appends`, which lead to an infinite loop of loading > appending > loading > appending ... You might be running into something similar here, in which case, you'd have to iterate and map `show_personal` onto each record manually, which isn't too hard, maybe `$ordenesTrabajos->map(function ($o) { $o->show_personal = $o->getShowPersonalAttribute(); });` (looks weird, but `$o->show_personal = $o->show_personal` is too)

Comment: Tim's answer makes sense If the `personal` attribute on the `OrdenesTrabajo` is itself an accessor. You might be overcomplicating your data retrieval though. It sounds like there is a relationship between `OrdenesTrabajo` and `Personal` that could be defined as such. Then it would be as simple as loading the relationship.

Comment: Yes, there _should_ be a relationship between `OrdenesTrabajo` and `Personal`, but it's ancient code and I'm afraid I can't afford changing it right now, but I might do it. Also, `Personal` does have another appends attribute wich calls `OrdenesTrabajo`, so everything you both are saying makes sense here, it's looping. I'll see if Tim's solution can help me or change the code and make it a relationship. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed it, thanks to Tim and msmahon who very much accurately pointed out my problem, it was a loop between two appended fields, both in `OrdenesTrabajo` model and `Personal` model. In `Personal` model I had:

```
    protected $appends= [
      'show_orden_trabajo', 
    ];

    public function getShowOrdenTrabajoAttribute() {
      $data = [];
      $arrOT = OrdenesTrabajo::All();
      foreach ($arrOT as $key => $value) {
        $arrPersonal = json_decode($value->personal);
        if($arrPersonal) {
          if(in_array($this->id, $arrPersonal)) {
            $data[] = $value;
          }
        }
      }
      return $data;      
    }
```

so, it was appending > looping > appending > looping as Tim said. My solution was to make the `show_orden_trabajo` field in `Personal` model hidden instead of appends, and that field was used just once so when I need it I just make it visible like so:

`$per = Personal::find($id)->makeVisible('show_orden_trabajo');`

The original problem is that I should've had a relationship between these two models. But this made the trick, just hope in the future I don't need both fields when calling via API. Thank you both for your answers